# Spring mass problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A possible side project:  The spring-loaded ride.

Passengers board a carriage and a spring takes them for a ride.  The spring begins at a position $30$ meters below equilibrium and is released from rest. The displacement $x$ at time $t$ would be the solution to $m\ddot{x}+b\dot{x}+kx=0,\;x(0)=30,\;\dot{x}(0)=0$ or

```
dsolve('m*D2x + b*Dx + k*x = 0', 'x(0) = 30', 'Dx(0) = 0')
```

in MATLAB.

The value of $m$ may range between $500$ and $800$kg for this exercise.  I'd like you to come up with a $b$ (drag coefficient) and $k$ (spring constant) that cause the following to happen, if possible:

The motion is undamped and oscillations continue to be higher and lower than $3$m above and below the equilibrium point for at least $20$ seconds.
We should get more than $25$m away from the equilibrium position at least twice:  once at the very beginning, when the carriage is $30$ meters below it, and perhaps the first time we hit the peak of the motion.  Getting this distance more than twice is even better.
The acceleration should never be greater than $5$g to avoid injuries or loss of consciousness.

Can you find values of $b$ and $k$ that make this happen?

Comment: try simulation with some sliders to change the parameters and find the optimal values?

Comment: What have you tried? And are you sure the phrase "The motion is undamped" is correct? Undamped would require $b=0,$ and you would get pure sinusoidal motion. That's not only unphysical, it sort of contradicts the rest of the problem statement. Did you mean to say that it is underdamped?

Comment: It's undamped. Thanks for your response.